# Form doesn't accept all inputs rows in my form (input names missing(

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code and I need to get the count of inputs that I put in inserting the rows and input text form. Please can anyone help me?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount - 1);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML;
  cell2.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <form method="POST">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="s1[]" type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="s2[]" type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="insert" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>

<button onclick="myFunction()">more</button>

<?php if(isset($_POST[ 'submit']))
  {
    $count = count($_POST[ 's1']); 
    echo "<script>alert('".$count. "');</script>"; 
  } 
?>
```

Comment: what is your problem? explain?

Comment: When i click the button "more" the function Javascript insert a row to the table with input type= text but when i submit and click submit the row count of input text return all times 1

Comment: Hi @nuddzz : I posted my answer. Please check it out. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should put the table inside the form:

```
<form method="POST">
    <table id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="s1[]" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="s2[]" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="insert" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this and noth change, look when I add <tr> <td> <input type ="text" name="s1[ ]".....  Manually i works perfectly so iii think the prob is from Javascript because when i insert the row it doesn't appear with form

Comment: So when you put the table inside the form, you click on "more" a few times and then you click "insert",  the alert still returns 1?

Comment: Does the page reload then you press "insert"? I've added this to the button to prevent that. `<button onclick="myFunction(); return false;">more</button>` Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr.

You can have an entire table inside a form. You can have a form inside a table cell. You cannot have part of a table inside a form.

Use one form around the entire table. Then either use the clicked submit button to determine which row to process (to be quick) or process every row (allowing bulk updates).

Everything fine. Put your `<form>` & `</form`> outside table.
`<table></table>` should be inside `<form></form>`

```
<form method="POST">
    <table id="mytable">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="s1[]" type="text" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="s2[]" type="text" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="insert" />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

For more info, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237963/cant-put-php-form-in-a-table)

Comment: thank you dear Partykar it worked very well after i put <from> outside the table i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @nuddzz: Glad to help :). If you think, my answer helped you, then please mark it as correct answer as other user's will find this answer easily. Thanks.

Comment: What happened @nuddzz , why u unanswered my answer.

Comment: oh... how are you now??