# Datatables Jquery can not submit the POST from table

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I'm using a datatables jquery as a table plugin to show the data list from mysql.
its all fine, the script running well. But when iam try to submit the data form from each row, the page doesn't load anything.

This is my **source page.**

```
    <div id="product-grid" class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="txt-heading"><h3> Services </h3></div>
         <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover " id="dataTables-example">
         <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Price</strong></th>
                    <th name="kategori"><strong>Kategori</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Action</strong></th>
                </tr>   
        </thead>
        <?php
        $product_array = runQuery("SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY id ASC");
        if (!empty($product_array)) { 
            foreach($product_array as $key=>$value){
        ?>
        <form class="form-group" method="post" action="?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong><?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="product-price"><?php echo $format->angka($product_array[$key]["price"]); ?></td>
                <td>    <?php echo $product_array[$key]["kategori"]; ?> </td>
                <td>    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" /> </td>
                <td> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        <?php }
        }?>
</tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

these code i load from admin.php through index.php page..

```
<link href="<?php echo ASSETS.'bootstrap/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css';?>" rel="stylesheet">  
<script src="<?php echo ASSETS.'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js';?>"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo ASSETS.'bootstrap/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js';?>"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo ASSETS.'bootstrap/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js';?>"></script>
```

What i want is, when the user click submit, the form is post to the action.php to handle a script.

Thankyou..

Comment: any related code you can post?

Comment: @RFLdev the code above in my post is my current code right now. and i just stuck in thats problem i have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr.

You can have an entire table inside a form. You can have a form inside a table cell. You cannot have part of a table inside a form.

Use one form around the entire table. Then either use the clicked submit button to determine which row to process (to be quick) or process every row (allowing bulk updates).

Everything fine. Put your `<form>` & `</form`> outside table.

`<table></table>` should be inside `<form></form>`

**For Example :** (Correct Way)

```
<form method="POST">
    <table id="mytable">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="s1" type="text" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="s2" type="text" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="insert" />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And, This is wrong Approach.

```
<table id="mytable">
    <form method="POST">
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <input name="s1" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                 <input name="s2" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="insert" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

For more info, check [Can't put PHP form in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237963/cant-put-php-form-in-a-table) & [Form doesn't accept all inputs rows in my form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613193/form-doesnt-accept-all-inputs-rows-in-my-form-input-names-missing/33640051#33640051)

Since OP Asked The way to do.

My opinion will be, use `<table></table>` for only displaying data. Because you can't use `<form></form>` inside `<table></table>`. Make One Column Action, where you pass value to other page with that row id. And, In that page (Other page as i wrote), Display data (if required) of that product including `Quantity` to submit. It's just a suggestion. Hope You Understand.

```
<div id="product-grid" class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="txt-heading"><h3> Services </h3></div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover " id="dataTables-example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Price</strong></th>
                <th name="kategori"><strong>Kategori</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Action</strong></th>
                </tr>   
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            $product_array = runQuery("SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY id ASC");
            if (!empty($product_array)) { 
                foreach($product_array as $key=>$value) {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong><?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?></strong></td>
                        <td class="product-price"><?php echo $format->angka($product_array[$key]["price"]); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $product_array[$key]["kategori"]; ?> </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="Edit-Somepage.php?id=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["id"]; ?>">Edit</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php }
            }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit-Somepage.php**

```
<?
$id=$_GET['id'];
$product_array = runQuery("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE id='$id'");
foreach($product_array as $key=>$value) {
    $product_name=$product_array[$key]["name"];
    $product_price=$format->angka($product_array[$key]["price"]);
}
?>
<form class="form-group" method="post" action="submit-SomePage.php">
    <?echo $product_name;?><br>
    <?echo $product_price;?><br>
    <input type='hidden' value="<?echo $id;?>" name='ProductId'>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" /> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

**submit-SomePage.php**

```
<?
$product_id=$_POST['ProductId'];

using this $product_id save/update/submit product.
//Update Query.
?>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but the other problem is. I need to use dataTables jquery plugin as my table script. these script help me to shorting the data of table. 
For example, to use the datatable i must using <table id="datatables-example-id"> ......content of table ..... </table>.
If i separate the table like your answer above, the result of each row will show in different table...

Comment: Hi @pitokeraf : Yeah, Use It. But, just to display data. Make one column 'Action'. In which you pass Id of that row to some other page to submit data. Because, it's not possible to use `<form></form>` inside any child element of `<table></table>`. Hope you understand.

Comment: sorry, you meant i have to make another page to process the data? i have it. I have included the page in form action. Or can you explain to me in one sample code? Please help me....

Comment: Yeah Sure @pitokeraf. Wait for 10 min. I Will be ready with my code.

Comment: yeah sure @Nana Partykar

Comment: @pitokeraf : I updated my answer. You can go through it. I just gave idea. Not mandatory to use this way only. But, You can explore your ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. What i understand is, i do not need an form to submit the data, just use a hyperlink to goto other page to process the data.
Thankyou Nana Partykar.. I will try the way.

Comment: Ok @pitokeraf : Try this code. I'm sure it will work. If you think, this answer helped you, then i will suggest you tick it as correct answer as it will help other user to find it easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Getting help form @nana answer, you can so do this

Form is invalid child of ,  but it is valid under

```
<tr>
<td> some field
<td> some other field
<td> **<form method="post">**somefield, some hidden field**</form>**
</td>
```

This way you have form element inside  which is valid. You can include hidden element that you need and thus form can be submitted from inside jQuery DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="usrname" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="email" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="login">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. 
Yes, thats right if only one or two row. how about result from database. we must using foreach or while... 
I meant, is every single row have a submit post.